# Unable to update/delete item from table even with on_delete=CASCADE

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to make a Cooking Recipe Portal DB and none of the DELETE queries work for me.

**Here are my tables/models related to the error:**

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredientid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class IngredientRecipe(models.Model):
    ingredientid = models.ForeignKey("Ingredient", to_field="ingredientid", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    recipeid = models.ForeignKey("Recipe", to_field="recipeid", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("ingredientid", "recipeid")

class IngredientNutrition(models.Model):
    nutritionid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ingredientid = models.ForeignKey("Ingredient", to_field="ingredientid", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #ingredientid = models.OneToOneField(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    portionsize = models.FloatField(max_length=24)
    calories = models.IntegerField()
    fat = models.IntegerField()
    protein = models.IntegerField()
    sodium = models.IntegerField()
    carbs = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("nutritionid", "ingredientid"), )
```

**Table Schemas:**

Ingredient Table
[image: Ingredient Table]

IngredientRecipe Table
[image: IngredientRecipe Table]

IngredientNutrition Table
[image: IngredientNutrition Table]

**Issue:** Say i want to delete *ingredient.ingredientID = 20* or *ingredient.name = 'Corn Starch'*, it won't let me delete because ingredientID = 20 is still referenced by the table IngredientNutrition.

**Code I tried:** `DELETE FROM recipeportaldb_ingredient WHERE recipeportaldb_ingreident.ingredientid = 20;`

**Error message:** Key (ingredientid)=(20) is still referenced from table "recipeportaldb_ingredientnutrition"
If I try other ingredientid values, error changes to ... from table "recipeportaldb_ingredientrecipe"

I tried altering the parameters inside the models.ForeignKey and changed parameters in various keys in different tables to see if it allowed me to delete.

Comment: 1) What is the exact code you are using to do the delete? 2) Have you looked at the tables using `psql` to see what their actual schema are? 3) What is the exact error message you are getting from Django and/or in the Postgres log.? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: I updated my question post with more information! Thank you

Comment: 1) You have not shown the actual table schema as it is in the database, please do so. 2) If you are actually doing `DELETE FROM ...` without going through the model then it will not work.  See [Django FK](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) 'CASCADE  Cascade deletes. Django emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE and also deletes the object containing the ForeignKey.' Note `emulates` so this only works if you go through the model.

Comment: I posted screenshots, are these the table schema you're referring to from what I researched on google. I don't exactly understand what you mean by go through the model.

Comment: Do not post textual information as images, copy and past the text to your question.You still not have answered whether you are doing this through the model or via manual query? The manual version will not work as the FK statement on the table does not have `ON CASCADE DELETE`, that is handled via the Django model code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to delete the `IngredientNutrition` object that refers to the `Ingredient` object you want to delete, then you can delete the `Ingredient` obj

```
DELETE FROM recipeportaldb_IngredientNutrition 
WHERE ingredientid = 20;
```

Then...

```
DELETE FROM recipeportaldb_ingredient 
WHERE ingredientid = 20;
```

If you are using django to handle this, it can be done with single line:

```
Ingredient.objects.get(ingredientid=20).delete()
```